# Is it safe to use PHP to deliver JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, browser, security

I'm using the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/php/dictionary.php">

</script>
```

dictionary.php is a PHP Script that outputs JavaScript code. The reason I am using dictionary.php to generate JavaScript is that certain values in JavaScript depends on the Locale & User.

I was wondering if this technique is as safe as using Javascript file directly?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with it. The script gets generated on the server and gets sent to the client. What are you concerned about specifically?

Comment: In that case, it's just as safe as including a regular JS file. Any issues will come from your code and not which method you use to include it on your page.

Answer (score 3):

No, it's not safe as you want different scripts for different users. The script will be cached, so a user may get the script for a different user who was logged in on the same computer earlier.

If you need it to be safe, generate a code for the logged in user, and send that in the querystring when you request the script, so that you can verify that the correct user gets the script. As the URLs will be different, the will also be cached separately.

Comment: If I put a random querystring with it like src="/php/dictionary.php?random={{RANDOM_KEY}}"

or If I set the HTTP Headers to past date

Comment: But, I like your idea to have different scripts but in my case I also have to include language translations so there would be too many scripts.

Comment: @user395881: The random value would make it *almost* safe, as there is still a tiny risk that you would get the same random number as a previous request. As the generated script depends on user and locale, you already have the different scripts, the only difference would be the query string that ensures that a user doesn't get the wrong script.

Answer (score 1):

Javascript will only affect the client-side. Unless you are exposing client-side operations that affect other users in the .php file, in which case cross-site scripting may be abused, it should be fine.

**Reference**: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting

This is safe as any potential exploit they may pursue would only affect the client-side, given that all server-side files called from the Javascript are patched for security as well.